# How to prevent page refresh on trigger function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I click on the list the page is refreshed, this is due to Trigger, but I donot want the page to refresh

```
 base.$rootElement.data('val',dataArr.toString()).trigger('data-value-change');

 $(window).click(function(e) {
     console.log('window clicked'); 
     base.$optionTray.hide();
});

this.filterElByTagnew.on('data-value-change', function (e) {  self.cummulativeOnChangeHandler(); });
```

**//HTML**

```
<div class="js-multiselectDropdown">
    <div style="background-color: white">
        <div class="action-btn " data-action="colex"><span>Choose Tag</span></div>

        <div class="eG2Col list-show" data-action="option-tray">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>

        <div data-action="checkbox-tray" class="hidden">
            <input type="checkbox" value="5G" />5G</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Connectivity"  />Connectivity</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Digital transformation" />Digital transformation</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Radio system"  />Radio system</br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Mobile"  />Mobile</br>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does cummulativeOnChangeHandler do?

Comment: searchConfig.tag = this.filterElByTagnew.data('val').split(",");
Just storing the value by spliting it

Comment: and data-value-change event is triggered by/on what?

Comment: <div class="js-multiselectDropdown" data-val="5G,Connectivity,Digital transformation,Radio system">

Whenever the root element is updated with data-val, the event is triggered

Comment: how do you track the change of data-val?

Comment: When the user click on the li, a trigger event is called which trigger an event and it is listened by this.filterElByTagnew. and then the value is stored in array.